# Enable regular users to install new packages from both - Gnome-software and apt

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, sudo, sudoedit

I'm on Debian 9 with Gnome. I would like to enable regular users to install new packages from both:

1. Gnome software center (GUI application), and
2. apt (via command line).

How can I achieve both?

Comment: Allowing users to install packages is equivalent to giving them root access, so you might as well add them to `sudoers`.

Comment: @StephenKitt, indeed? Why is it equivalent to giving them root access? I wanted to restrict them from tweaking the system but be able to try out additional apps...

Comment: When you manipulate packages, their maintainer scripts run as root, so any user who can supply a package for installation and install it can run a script as root. Even if that’s prevented (which isn’t all that easy), a user capable of installing packages can force a conffile conflict and get a root shell that way.

Comment: @StephenKitt, in my case the users are not that tech savvy so I don't expect such hacks... is there a way to do what I'm looking for anyway? Thank you!

Comment: For Gnome Software, it can be achieved through writing PolKit rules. This would also allow using `pkcon` on the command line, although not `apt`.  I think there is a problem that this is not symmetric though.  You can permit installing packages from repos and it usually works fine... but when you allow uninstalling a package, it is easier to accidentally break the system.